# How do I display docs from GitHub in an Angular website?

Tags: angular, github, gitbook

I have been trying to come up with a solution to provide documentation of my portal (written in Angular) to users. I looked at Angular Website and it appears that they maintain their documentation in GitHub. I am curious how they were able to present the documentation in Github on the Angular Website?

Here's the link I am referring to: [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/docs)

I would like my portal to have similar functionality including left and right navigations. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is called GitHub pages. It's a feature anyone on GitHub can use. How exactly the Angular team generates their documentation is a different question.  https://pages.github.com/

Comment: Right. I think that's what I want to know. How exactly the Angular team generates their documentation from GitHub pages and how I can use similar mechanism to stand up mine.

Comment: It's complicated. They use JsDoc annotations, their own doc parser and their own website builder. I'm not sure I can figure it all out, and they also generate API documentation. I'll see if I can find the github repo for their website generator.